# How do action events work with players' turns, need help showing which card the user played before the computer shows what card it played

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Im creating an uno game and it is almost fully functional and i'm using javaFX to create it. It is Computer vs User and the problem is that when a user clicks on a card button, the middle card is supposed to be replaced with that card and then the computer goes, however what ends up happening is that the computer goes right away and so you only see the computer's card played in the middle. I am sure this has something to do with how i structured my code specifically the action event pertaining to the button clicked. However, since this is my first ever java GUI and i am fairly new to java i am struggling to understand how to structure it so that i am able to show the user's move. Also due to this, i am unable to implement a skip card even though i have tried using a boolean and creating another method i think the main problem lies within how the main gameloop and the actionevent inside is set up.

This method is called and it checks for a button click and then gets the index of the button in the player's arraylist/hand/ The boolean was my attempt at implementing a skip card but what kept happening is the computer would always play right after the user's move when a skip card was played.

```
public void gameLoop(){
        for(int i =0; i<buttonList.size();i++){
            buttonList.get(i).setOnAction((ActionEvent)->{
                indexOfHandButton = buttonList.indexOf((Button)ActionEvent.getSource());

                humanMakeMove();
                if(!isReverseTurn()) {
                    computerMakeMove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This method used the index given from the gameloop actionevent and makes the actual move in the backend. It then clears the hbox containing the users hands and calls showhumanHand which fills it up with the updated cards and similarily with the middle card. The if statements to try and implement the skip cards have not worked, i have also tried creating a new action even inside the if statement and creating a method or recursively calling humanMakeMove but of course the index will be the same and will cause an error.

```
 public void humanMakeMove() {
        String result = human.makeMove(game, theDeck, indexOfHandButton, computer);
        if(result.equals("skip")){
            setReverseTurn(true);
        }
        hbHumanHandBtn.getChildren().clear();
        hbMiddleCard.getChildren().remove(middle);
        middle = generateMiddleCard();
        hbMiddleCard.getChildren().add(middle);
        showHumanHand();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + buttonList);
        System.out.println(result);
        if (middleCard.getType() != null) {
            if (middleCard.getType().equals("skip") && isReverseTurn()) {
                System.out.println(isReverseTurn());
                gameLoop();
                setReverseTurn(false);

            }
        }
    }
```

So my main question is how can i restructure this or add something that allows for the user's card to show in the middle before the computer goes right away, i have tried a timer/sleep method too. And my skip card doesnt work but i think that has to do with how i set up my action listener which is messing up two problems. Thank you for reading this and let me know if you have any input!

Comment: Try using [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks i tried using that and it works but there is one problem. Let's say you play the game really fast then what happens is the user can click two cards in a row before the computer's card is displayed. I was thinking of disabling the buttons so the user cant go until the computer makes its move?

Comment: You can do things like disable event handlers while the pause transition is running or you can use a stackpane and move some other empty pane to the front while the pause transition is running and to the back when it finishes. I like the second idea better.

Comment: @Sedrick Okay thanks for the ideas, i already used disable button and it worked out but i have another question, how do i implement the skip card? Right now when the user clicks on a skip card i tried setting a boolean checking if a skip card was played and if it is then calling the gameloop again and i even tried creating a new action listener then after the second move, resetting the boolean to false. However this never worked and the computer always goes right after. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `gameloop` method is most likely implemented wrong. It's very rare that an event handler needs to be constantly done in a loop. Given the small amount of code, it's hard to tell. Good luck coding.

Comment: Yea i altered that method and separated the eventhandler from the computer's move and renamed the methods and now it works. Thanks for the help